# Terminology conventions in mathematics

Tags: terminology, definition

I am writing a paper where I have more than one lemma (Lemma 1, Lemma 2, and Lemma 3) and when I cite them together I was wondering is it more appropriate to say, for example,

> because of Lemmas 1-3

or

> because of Lemmata 1-3

I found out yesterday that Lemmata is the plural form of lemma but I had never seen it before used. Which one is conventionally used in mathematics?

Comment: I suppose it is a matter of taste of the editor but I think no-one in this day and age would have any issue whatsoever with "lemmas" (which I'm certain I've seen many times) whereas most would consider "Lammata" absurdly stuffy and formal even if it is considered proper.  I kind of like it I confess but in a humorful overly precise kind of way.

Comment: Lemmata actually is the transcription of the Greek plural (λῆμματα).

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing we never write Lemmata in the literature because no one knows that the actual plural is Lemmata and not Lemmas. Since English is a very internationalized language and most English speakers are not native speakers, it becomes a reflex to write Lemmas for most people and sometimes this reflex can easily push native speakers into doing the same mistake if they hear/read it everyday.

I myself use Lemmas for the same reasons. It seems kind of pointless to correct this "English mistake" if it goes against mainstream use, because it's just gonna raise questions in the reader's head instead of making him/her understand you just wanted to write the word in its plural form.

Hope that helps,

Comment: As a non native speaker I obviously agree with you, but if some people begin to do it (teacher for example) by chain reaction it can be apply in some years. It could be a good exercize to predict in how much time haha.

Comment: @Shadock : It already applies. I only see Lemmata when people ask why we don't write Lemmata.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you say and I am a nitpick so i say lemmata  , i may be the only french who say "i want to eat pizze" and not "pizzas" :P

Comment: @Shadock : You are definitely the only French person that says pizze! Latin is being less and less taught in schools so people also care less and less about the Latin origin of plurals. The funny part is that you insist on saying Lemmata but you make a mistake while writing "exercize" (it's exercise). So don't push it, make your life easy ;)

Comment: Keypad mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

At the time that "lemma" is admitted as a word in a particular language, it should be applied accordingly to pluralize in that language no matter what the ethymological Greek (or Latin) plural whatever it is (in French the plural of "lemme" is "lemmes" and so is in Spanish, with an S at the end of the word).

The difference can be many ways; for example in Italian "paparazzi" is plural and "paparazzo" is the corresponding singular but many people don't use this singular to refer just one paparazzo; in Spanish the plural of "hermosa mujer" is "hermosaS mujereS" (twice S) but in English the plural of "beautiful woman" is "beautiful women" (non at all S), etc.

Comment: It’s common for the plural form of foreign words to be used as a singular in English when they don’t match the normal English pattern for plurals. Besides _paparazzi_, there’s also _piroshki_, _panini_, &c. It works in the other direction, too: _gyros_ undergoes a back-formation to _gyro_.